# How to interprete this Quantile Plot?

Tags: multiple-regression, interpretation, residuals

I did a multiple regression analysis for several production sites with energy consumption as dependent variable, and 2 other independent predictors (Floor space, production).

When checking the residuals for a bias, i got this excel-standard-quantiles-plot, with a very funny shape: the curve has two linear parts with different gradient. On top of that there is one clear outlier (that is just a site much bigger than the others, but I dont see a reason to exclude it, as it doesnt show a very big residual).

Does anyone have an Idea, (1) why I find this two very distinct slopes in the quantile plot, and (2) how I could interprete them?

Thanks!

Lukas

[image]

Comment: So this is a plot of the residuals? Then you have a strong positive bias.

Comment: This is characteristic of a mixture distribution (with two components, one located near 400,000 with a weight of 0.6 and the other near 1,000,000, the latter with significantly greater variance).  However, because (1) it's obviously not a plot of residuals and (2) we don't know anything useful about the nature of this model, it's hard to see how anyone could provide specific advice about interpreting it.

Comment: thanks for your comment, its helping a lot! So, the gradient gives me an indication about the variance of that part of the sample? So I would interpret that smaller sites (up to approximately 600.000 kWh) are more comparable than bigger sites, given the set of variables that I used (It is a multiple regression model, estimating heat demand Y from the independent variables Floor area, Heating degree days and production quantity. sample size is about 40). about 10 sites fit the criteria ">600.000 kWh annual heat consumption", about 30 sites are smaller.